# How do I recreate /dev/shm after removing it by mistake?

Tags: filesystem

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 and I removed by mistake few folders from `/dev/`. As a result i have some problems with some applications like Chrome, which is not able to work.

Comment: Most of the contents of `/dev/` are created dynamically. Have you tried rebooting?

Answer (score 3):

`/dev/shm` is a way processes use to **sh**are **m**emory (see *man shm_open* for more information). Its content is determined by the processes you run, therefore you can't "download" it. You can however re-create it.

On Ubuntu, `/dev/shm` is a symlink to `/run/shm`; this is the command that you have to use to re-create it:

```
sudo ln -s /run/shm /dev/shm
```

This action is also performed by the */etc/init/mounted-dev.conf* Upstart script. This means that (as it was already suggested) rebooting your system without doing anything special is an another way of fixing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

/dev/shm is nothing but implementation of traditional shared memory concept. It is an efficient means of passing data between programs. One program will create a memory portion, which other processes (if permitted) can access. This will result into speeding up things on Linux.

you need to add or modify entry in /etc/fstab file so that system can read it after the reboot. Edit, /etc/fstab as a root user, enter:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

add /dev/shm entry as follows to set size to XXGB

```
none      /dev/shm        tmpfs   defaults,size=XXG        0 0
```

replace XX by the size you wish to use as shared memory.

Save and close the file.

Now reboot.

---

If you just want to restore your old /dev/shm file then use the current running memory which is a copy of /dev/shm

```
sudo cp /run/shm /dev/shm -r
```

then reboot